# Importar modulos dinamicamente en python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Muy buenas tardes a todos. Actualmente me ha surgido la inquietud de aprender a importar módulos dinamicamente en python, logrando acceder a todos los módulos que tiene mi proyecto en un solo llamado, pues la idea de mi proyecto es que el usuario que desee pueda agregar nuevos módulos y después pueda decidir que modulo desea utilizar especificando dicha solicitud a través de parámetros, por ejemplo si lo que el usuario digito se encuentra dentro de la carpeta de módulos del proyecto, haga uso de ello sino que utilice por defecto el modulo principal. La base de mi proyecto es:

```
carpeta_principal
|
|----modules
|    |
|    |----modulo_principal.py
|    |----otro_modulo.py
|
|----main.py
```

He estado averiguando y documentandome al respecto.Logre encontrar algo que me fue de utilidad, lo puse en practica y me funcionado, lo cual es:

```py
def import_from(module, name):
    module = __import__(module, fromlist=[name])
    return getattr(module, name)
```

El cual recibe:

```py
module_import = import_from("modules", "modulo_principal")
```

Al utilizar esta lógica dentro del `main.py` y luego acceder a los métodos que tiene el `modulo_principal` funciona perfectamente pero ¿Y si el usuario decide a través de parámetros que desea acceder a `otro_modulo`? Me gustaría saber si alguno de ustedes sabe y me puede explicar como lograr implementar esta idea en mi proyecto. Muchas gracias.

Comment: tengo entendido que está desaconsejado del uso directo de `__import__` para importar programaticamente, lo "normal" es usar `importlib.import_module(...)`, mira https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#__import__

Comment: @UselesssCat Si, tienes razón, lo corregiré en mi código. ¿Tienes alguna idea de la pregunta que planteo? Gracias.

Comment: @GustavoAdolfoRodriguez Tu pregunta: *¿Y si el usuario decide a través de parámetros que desea acceder a otro_modulo?* no es clara para mi, para mi es una condicional que no implica una pregunta que se puede reducir a : *¿Si X?*

Comment: @UselesssCat Si, algo asi, pero ¿como se si x esta dentro de la carpeta "modules" y es un modulo? ya que lo que hago con el método es simplemente importar lo que hay uno a uno escribiéndolo directamente en el codigo y creo que no es lo correcto.

Comment: Creo que lo enfocas mal. Da igual el módulo que quiera importar el usuario ya que tu código podrá usar el nombre que quiera a ese módulo. En tu caso, `module_import` es el *namespace* con el que puedes acceder a las propiedades del módulo importado, no tienes porqué usar `modulo_principal` si no quieres.

Comment: @ChemaCortes Me hago una idea de lo que quieres decir, pero por ejemplo, ¿Como podría evitar tener un error cuando el módulo que intente importar no exista? Se que bastaría con una condición, o eso creo pero me pierdo un poco a la hora de intentar realizarla. Agradezco su comprensión y su apoyo.

Comment: @GustavoAdolfoRodriguez El sistema de módulos de python es bastante complicado de explicar. No es tan trivial como importar este o ese módulo. Te recomiendo que eches un vistazo a los ejemplos y sigas alguno de ellos: https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importing-programmatically

Comment: @ChemaCortes Muchas gracias por tu aporte. Me pondré entonces a revisar dicha documentación.